# find the equation of sine (or relevant) function with trend to fit a curve or fill gap

Tags: matlab, interpolation

I want to fill a gap of [temperature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMzmD.jpg) (hourly) data. After plotting it appears to be the gap can be fit by using a sine function with a trend. Now i would like to find the equation.
Any suggestions will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: It doesn't look sinusoidal to me. I would just [fit a polynomial](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polyfit.html) to the range [700,1400].

Comment: Hey @lemon thanks for your suggestion. with your idea i tried polyfit with 30 coeff. later when I tried to evaluate. it is not working.

Comment: With 30 coefficients?! I would do only 3 or 4... Fitting a curve in this way will only produce a smooth function over this interval though; if you wish to include the local fluctuations then you will need to add, say, a random Gaussian distribution on top of the interpolate.

Comment: yes, when I use less than 4 coefficients I am getting low frequency fit. where my interest is , I would like to reproduce other(at-least tidal frequencies which are in 24 - 48 hours) frequencies also. And you are mentioning Gaussian distribution, can you give me some references if possible to fit.

Comment: I don't know of any references but it's fairly straightforward. You could approximate the standard deviation of the fluctuations (I suggest doing it by eye - I would guess about 0.05 - but if you want a slightly more rigorous way then let me know). Then for each point along your interpolant you add a random variable that is Gaussian distributed (in matlab use [normrnd](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/stats/normrnd.html))